# Create nested JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, slim

I'm trying to create a JSON array to send it to my web service. This is how my json should look like:

```
[{
  "tipus": 1,
  "proveidor": 3,
  "atributs": {
    "atribut":{
      "id": 1,
      "valor": 8
    },
    "atribut":{
      "id": 2,
      "valor": 500
    }
  }
}]
```

So, I have two general values "tipus" and "proveidor" and multiple "atributs" each "atribut" is composed with "id" and "valor".

When I construct the json I get this instead of what I want:

```
[
2:{
  "tipus": 1,
  "proveidor": 3, 
1:{
      "id": 1,
      "valor": 8
  },
0:{
      "id": 2,
      "valor": 500
    }
}]
```

This is how I'm building the json:

```
    // For every founded in $scope.atrb i need to create an 'atribut' element into my json
        $scope.a = [];
                            var key;
                            for(key in $scope.atrb){
                                var newField =  {
                                                "idatributs_actiu": $scope.atrb[key].idatributs_actiu, 
                                                "nomAtribut": $scope.atrb[key].nomAtribut, 
                                                "valor": $scope.atrb[key].valor,
                                                "idActiu": $routeParams.idTipusActiu,
                                                "value": "",
                                                "ordre": $scope.atrb[key].ordre,
                                                "idatributs_generics": $scope.atrb[key].idatributs_generics
                                            };
                                $scope.a.push(newField);
                            }
                            $scope.f = $scope.a;
                        });

var generics = {
                       "nom": $scope.nom,
                       "tipus": $routeParams.idTipusActiu,
                       "proveidor": $scope.proveidor.id
                   };
                   $scope.a.push(generics);
```

It's my first project with angular and I'm not sure if I'm building the json appropriately, basically i use an array to build a json but I don't know how to nested it  'atribut' inside 'atributs'.

The main idea is to read the 'generics' atributes and then loop through 'atributs' and read all 'atribut' element getting the properties.

Regards

Comment: your initial `JSON` structure is not exactly correct. You should consider `"atributs"` as a `JSONArray` and not a `JSONObject`

Comment: or just a JS array and not a JSON array, since JSON arrays and JSON objects don't exist.

Comment: thanks for correction but I guess you get the point :)

Comment: thanks @S4beR and Kevin B but how can I do it with angular. I'm really lost about this topic

Comment: @proktovief just use javascript to do it. This is very basic object/array generation.

Comment: so, if I understood, I have to do an array which containing: 'general object' + second array (called attributes) which contains 'atribut' objects. All this 'general' and 'atribut' should be objects?

Comment: `$scope.a` should contain an array with a single object. (`a` is a TERRIBLE name by the way.)  That object should contain properties tipus, proveidor, and atributs. atributs should contain an array of objects. Just like the structure you specified at the top. I literally just described it top to bottom.

Comment: yes it's true I did it like you say and now the json is well done. It's so easy, by the way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like S4beR and Kevin B told me, I just need to do an JS array. This is in my controller:

```
var obj = { generics: g, atributs: $scope.a };
```

> g: it's an object with the generic properties
>
> $scope.a: this is an array with 'atribut' objects which contais all
>   the properties I need save to.